# Conditional statement perl5

Tags: perl

Which of the following cannot be used in a conditional statement ?

while ,  if-else  ,  until , if-elsif-else

or the answer is simple None of these ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming) is a good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no restrictions at all in using any kind of statements inside a BLOCK of a conditional statement, so the answer is that **all of them** can be used.

1. *while* example:

   ```
   use warnings;
   use strict;
   local $\="\n";
   my $count=10;
   if ($count) {
       while ($count!=0) {
           print $count--; #will print 10, 9, 8, ..., 1
       }
   }
   ```
2. *if-else* example:

   ```
   use warnings;
   use strict;
   my $count=10;
   if ($count) {
       if ($count>5) {
           print 'greater than 5';
       }
       else {
           print 'lower or equal to 5';
       }
   }
   ```
3. *until* example:

   ```
   use warnings;
   use strict;
   local $\="\n";
   my $count=10;
   if ($count) {
       until ($count==0) {
           print $count--; #will print 10, 9, 8, ..., 1
       }
   }
   ```
4. *if-elsif-else* example:

   ```
   use warnings;
   use strict;
   my $count=10;
   if ($count) {
       if ($count>5) {
           print 'greater than 5';
       }
       elsif ($count==5) {
           print 'equal to 5';
       }
       else {
           print 'lower than 5';
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary code can be used in the BLOCK of a conditional statement.

```
if (f()) {
   while (g()) {
      h();
   }
}
```

You can even have arbitrary code in the condition expression by using `do`.

```
if (do {
      my $rv;
      while (!$rv && f()) {
         $rv ||= g();
      }
      $rv
}) {
   h();
}
```